Centering color box without changing spacing
I want my color boxes to be horizontally centered by default, but when I set halign = center, it massively spaces out the text, which I do not want.
I get the right output by not including a halign value and instead putting \centering at the start of every box, but I would prefer not to manually add \centering every time. Is this possible?
 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{colback=orange!15!white, colframe=white, halign = center}
\setcounter{section}{2}


\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}
    $Y = m\times x + c$
\end{mybox}

\end{document}


See the package manual at the section 18 Library theorems.
You could use ams align*:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcolorbox{mybox}{
    center,
    colback=orange!15!white, 
    colframe=white,
    ams align*
    }

\begin{document}
\begin{mybox}
    Y = m\times x + c
\end{mybox}
\end{document}



Thank you! I checked the manual to get the original align solution and didn't know which further section would be relevant.

@AinsleyPullen You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer.
